# mean.io Custom packages loading sequence

Tags: mean-stack

I've created two custom packages like below:

-mean package pkg1

-mean package pkg2

When I load a web page, on main menu bar, "pkg1" menu shows first then "pkg2" menu shows.
How could I change it to display "pkg2" menu first then "pkg1" menu?  e.g. "pkg2 menu"-"pkg1 menu" instead of "pkg1 menu"-"pkg2 menu"

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could make package 1 depend on package 2 in the mean.json, that might force them to load in a specific order. - credits @rjVapes